# python, multthreading, safe to use pandas "to_csv" on common file?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I've got some code that works pretty nicely.  It's a while-loop that goes through a list of dates, finds files on my HDD that corresponds to those dates, does some calculations with those files, and then outputs to a "results.csv" file using the command:

```
my_df.to_csv("results.csv",mode = 'a')
```

I'm wondering if it's safe to create a new thread for each date, and call the stuff in the while loop on several dates at a time?

MY CODE:

```
import datetime, time, os
import sys
import threading
import helperPY #a python file containing the logic I need

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter,sn, m_date):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.sn = sn
        self.m_date = m_date
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        m_runThis(sn, m_date)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def m_runThis(sn, m_date):
    helperPY.helpFn(sn,m_date)  #this is where the "my_df.to_csv()" is called

sn = 'XXXXXX'
today=datetime.datetime(2016,9,22) #
yesterday=datetime.datetime(2016,6,13) 

threadList = []
i_threadlist=0
while(today>yesterday):
    threadList.append(myThread(i_threadlist, str(today), i_threadlist,sn,today))
    threadList[i_threadlist].start()
    i_threadlist = i_threadlist +1
    today = today-datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing the file in multiple threads is not safe. But you can create a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to protect that one operation while letting the rest run in parallel. Your `to_csv` isn't shown, but you could create the lock

```
csv_output_lock = threading.Lock()
```

and pass it to `helperPY.helpFn`. When you get to the operation, do

```
with csv_output_lock:
    my_df.to_csv("results.csv",mode = 'a')
```

You get parallelism for other operations - subject to the GIL of course - but the file access is protected.

Comment: do I have to acquire/release the lock before/after calling helperFn()?

Comment: If you do it in a `with` clause, the lock is acquired when entering the block and automatically released when exiting. But the lock is only useful if it only wraps a bit of your code. If all of your work is done inside `helperFn` and you lock the entirety of `helperFn`, then you've defeated any advantage of the pool.

Comment: Theoretically it is not safe, but in practice Python's threading is constrained by global interpreter lock. Unless the code departs to C extension that releases this lock, even threading module are queued up I believe, which should make the IO safe. Opinions?

Comment: @Mal - python checks for thread switches periodically (somehow "every 100 instructions" comes to mind, but don't quote me on that) and releases the GIL when calling system functions such as file write. So you are guaranteed that other python threads will run while that write operation is in progress. The GIL does not mean that python is "IO safe"!